# Denote by n the nxn array having entires A i,j := sin(z i, j) where z i, j are uniformly distributed random numbers in (0,2pi]

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

I have found lots of help on creating arrays with specific number values but I cannot seem to find anything to help me set up the array in the first or second problems.

I am not asking for the answers to this assignment, this is just my first Python assignment so I am a beginner and cannot figure out how to set up the arrays I need as I am not given numbers.

So far, I have found this to create an empty array:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
my_array = np.empty([n, n])
```

And then set the value at coordinate i, j to to f(i, j).

```
for i, j in itertools.product(range(n), range(n)):
     my_array[i, j] = f(i, j)
```

I just cannot seem to figure out how to actually apply this code to my question. Would sin(z) be my f(i, j)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sin(z<sub>i,j</sub>) would be your f(i, j). It's probably more efficient to do without the loop, though:

```
np.sin((2 * np.pi) * (1 - np.random.random_sample((n, n))))
```

Comment: I cannot figure out how to import numpy. I'm getting an error when I try to import it